# Impala: partition every two weeks

Tags: sql, window-functions, impala, database-partitioning

I have the following database table:

my_table:

```
transaction_id    |  timestamp
---------------------------------
  001             |  2016-01-01
  002             |  2016-01-05
  003             |  2016-01-09
  004             |  2016-01-18
  005             |  2016-01-31
  006             |  2016-02-01
```

How do I partition the time by every two-weeks, so I can find how many transactions in each two-weeks period? Thanks!

Comment: i saw in the documentation that recursive cte's aren't supported.

Comment: Is recursive cte the only approach?

Comment: To begin with, how do you define the "week" -- starts on Sunday, or Monday? Week #1 contains Jan-01, or contains at least one workday of the new year?

Comment: Assuming that you have a formula to compute `WeekNumber(<date>)` then you just have to remove 1 from every **even** number so that Week #2 counts together with #1, #4 with #3, etc. `SELECT WeekNumber(ts) +WeekNumber(ts)%2 -1, COUNT(*) FROM wtf GROUP BY WeekNumber(ts) +WeekNumber(ts)%2 -1 `